# How do I CD to parent of deleted directory? (bash: cd: ..: No such file or directory)

Tags: linux, bash

I was running some simple commands in bash, and one of the commands I ran deleted my current working directory (nothing destructive, I just used git to checkout a branch where that directory doesn't exist).

Now I'm stuck in a deleted directory and cd doesn't seem to want to let me out:

```
$ cd ..
bash: cd: ..: No such file or directory
```

What's the easiest way to get out of this directory and back to its parent?

Note that the directory I am in is stored on an NTFS partition, which might explain why `cd ..` is giving an error, when that behavior doesn't seem to be the norm when executing cd from a deleted directory in Linux.

(Presumably retyping the absolute directory path and giving that to cd will work here, but the path the the parent directory is really long, and I'm lazy. Is there a better way to get to the parent directory than retyping its lengthy absolute path?)

Comment: just type `cd` again and you'll switch to your home dir and out of deleted directory.

Comment: @alexus: the question isn't about getting out of the deleted directory, it's about getting to its parent directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since bash doesn't seem to be recognising relative paths like `..` in this case, you'll have to use an absolute path instead. For example:

```
cd ~/path/to/dir
```

To simply get back to the parent directory, you could use the following, which is much faster than retyping the absolute path of the directory you're in:

```
cd "$(dirname "$(pwd)")"
```

Here's a simple function you can add to your `.bashrc` file to get this functionality with a single command (also supports an argument which you can use to specify how many levels to move up):

```
# Allow easily going up multiple directories, even when the current directory
# is a deleted folder on an NTFS share.
function up() {
  local dir=`pwd`
  local n=${1:-1};
  for ((; n>0; n--)) {
    dir=`dirname "$dir"`
  }
  cd "$dir"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

cd to an absolute path, not a path relative to the deleted directory.

E.g. `cd /home/username/`

Comment: The question asks how to get to the parent directory of the deleted one.

Answer (score 0):

### Tabbing

I suggest you read up on SSH, most shells allow for the use of tab to simplify typing commands.

If you type

> cd /h

Then press TAB, it will either show a list of directories you can tab too or if only one directory exists in / beginning with the letter h, such as home, it will automatically fill it out to

> cd /home

Once you get the grasp of it, it can save you a lot of time.

This solves you being lazy!

### Absolute Path

As you know you must CD to an absolute path.

A quick way to do this is to simple run

> cd

As this will in most systems take you to the users default directory, usually /home/$user

Comment: The question asks how to get to the parent directory of the deleted one.

Comment: The question also asks 'Is there a better way?' And also stating that the user is lazy, and if the user is going to be using shell frequently, most would say that knowing how to effectively use it, such features as knowing about tabbing are essential.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting stuck

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ mkdir 1
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$ cd 1
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 1]$ rm -rf ../1
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 1]$ cd ..
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 ~]$
```

... but you can always just run `cd` or `cd ~`

Comment: My guess is it has something to do with the directory being on an NTFS partition.